# How to add a location button in Mapbox like Google Maps' setMyLocationButtonEnabled?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, user-interface, mapbox

I'm very new to programming and I need to make an Android application. I just found out a good API other than Google Maps. It's called Mapbox. So, I've been following their documentation and as well as the sample codes but, I think some of their examples are outdated and that a few classes used are deprecated already. So, I was able to initialize the map already and put runtime permissions in my program.

Now, I don't know how to put a "location button" just like what Google Maps API use. I have programmed an app before using Google Maps API and I used the `mMap.getUISettings().setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` to show the location button. As I browsed the internet, I can't seem to find a code that brings that kind of UI in Mapbox. I found a few code snippets but then, as I've said, some of them are outdated. Also, they have their own .xml files which I don't have so when I try to copy their code, I always run into errors.

So, if you have any idea how to edit my files or if I need to add certain files into my project, please help me.

I will attach my files below. Thank you!

You can find the files in my GitHub repository: https://github.com/CyrilOlanolan/Tara-JMapbox

My MainActivity.java:

```
package com.garate.tara_j;

//Mapbox imports
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponentActivationOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponentOptions;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.OnCameraTrackingChangedListener;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.OnLocationClickListener;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.RenderMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.UiSettings;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private boolean isInTrackingMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        //ADD Aster's Map Style
        //mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri("mapbox://styles/cyrilolanolan/ck5gqdepj0u991io1g3743owe")
        mapboxMap.setStyle((Style.MAPBOX_STREETS), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

                // Map is set up and the style has loaded. Now you can add data or make other map adjustments.
                UiSettings uiSettings = mapboxMap.getUiSettings();
                uiSettings.setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
                enableLocationComponent(style);

            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style loadedMapStyle) {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

            // Permission sensitive logic called here, such as activating the Maps SDK's LocationComponent to show the device's location
            // Create and customize the LocationComponent's options
            LocationComponentOptions customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
                    .elevation(5)
                    .accuracyAlpha(.6f)
                    .accuracyColor(Color.BLUE)
                    .build();

            LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions =
                    LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
                            .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
                            .build();

            // Get an instance of the component
            final LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

            // Activate with options
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);

            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tara-J needs permission to function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                @Override
                public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                    enableLocationComponent(style);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions are required. Please restart Tara-J.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="7.0707"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="125.6087"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="13" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `LocationComponent` setup code looks great! Mapbox provides no built-in UI button. You'll need to add it to your XML layout. In the button's `onClick()`, get the `LocationComponent`'s last known location, and animate the camera to the last known location's coordinates:

```
findViewById(R.id.device_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

      Location lastKnownLocation = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLastKnownLocation();

      if (lastKnownLocation != null) {

        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
          .target(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude())) // Sets the new camera position
          .zoom(16)
          .bearing(0)
          .tilt(0)
          .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

        mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
          .newCameraPosition(position), 7000);
      }

    }
  });
```

[image]